# Spring Requestmapping with condition based on server-side parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

I have a controller (Spring Controller) that will serve json to a mobile app.

Various servers run our software. Not all will be configured to serve mobile requests.

I've added a bean of class Integer with the id of an object containing various system parameters necessary to handle requests.

This bean is defined in xml and autowired into the controller.

The autowiring uses (required = false) so we can run without a value defined in xml.

I have checked and found that the autowired Integer is indeed null if not defined in xml.

What I would like to do now is add to my requestmappings in a way that will match one method if that Integer is null and the regular method when the Integer is not null (basically, we'll reply with a standard json error object).

This seems like it'd be pretty straightforward with some sort of AOP, but I've little experience aside from using Spring. Most conditional info in the Requestmapping annotation seems to be based on request parameters, not server-side variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about interceptors?

Comment: Interesting. I'm looking into it right now and it seems like it might fit the bill nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is better use a `property-placeholder` to load a properties file from the classpath. In this way you can deploy the same **war** file in different servers and use a different property file for each server (putting it in the AS classpath).
Once you did it you can use a variable in your controller (or in an interceptor if you want to leave the controller's code clean) and do something like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    @Value("${mobile.enabled}")
    private boolean mobileEnabled;

@RequestMapping("/mobile")
public Object json(){
    if (!mobileEnabled)
        throw new IllegalStateException("This server can't do it!");
    }
    //create the json
    return result;
}
```

And a properties file like:

```
mobile.enabled=true
```

when you want to enable it, or false when don't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I find it answers a somewhat different question than the one I intended. The fact is that we have different profiles with their own context files. Defining a bean in the way I have may not be the 100% best way, but it fits what we have. What I really wanted to know is how I could adjust the requestmapping so that I could avoid copy-pasting the same if (!enabled) check at the beginning of each controller method (as that is pretty much what I have already).

Comment: If you have a common pattern for the URL of the various JSON, take a look at the Spring's [InterceptorHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors), otherwise you should use AOP, sincerly I try to avoid as much as possible the AOP way 'cause it seems to me too much _magic_. But with that way you can also define your own method annotation (something like `@Mobile`) and catch that method execution, (it's all written in the Spring docs, and a little bit longer to explain here).